# Unable install Pillow

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I tried installing `pillow` in the following ways:

```
$~ pip install Pillow  
$~ python3 -m pip install Pillow  
$~ python -m pip install Pillow
```

But none of these worked. How can I install `pillow`?

Comment: Did you get an error while installiing?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for all OSs

```
 $~ pip3 install pillow
```

Make sure you have a recent version of pip by running:

```
 $~ pip3 --version
```

Comment: I still get this error message tho. "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/yl/1p4qd4452gbgsfgxdt296pw00000gn/T/pip-install-bbm_dauk/pillow/setup.py'"'"';"

Comment: ```sudo pip3 install -U setuptools
```